# После перезагрузки страницы запускается js ajax и возвращать должен json, но он этого не делает, в чем проблема, подскажите, пожалуйста?

Tags: javascript, ajax

Вызов:

```
document.location.href = data.redirect_url;
load_pictures(groupka,valko,cat);
```

Сама функция, ответ есть, но не json.

```
function load_pictures(name, value, cat) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "{$config->root_url}/ajax/get_data.php?object=products&mode=tags_show_frontend&data=" + name + "&cat=" + cat +'&value=' + value,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data){
            $(".tags_filter").html(data.data);
        }
    });
}
```

Серверная часть:

```
$result = array('success' => true, 'data' => $html); 
header("Content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8"); 
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate"); 
header("Pragma: no-cache"); 
header("Expires: -1"); 
$json = json_encode($result); 
print $json;
```

Comment: ответ не JSON, а тогда что? можете показать?

Comment: А что возвращает? Если вы указали dataType: 'json' - это не значит, что придет json. Придет то, что ответит сервер по вашему url. К тому же, вы уверены, что здесь все верно: .html(data.data); ?

Comment: а что на серверной части написано?

Comment: @JurijJazdanov {"success":true,"data":"<div class=\"un_f1 \" ><div id=\"found-categories\"><div class=\"category-line
\"><a href=\"\u0441\u043c\u

Comment: @АлексейШиманский $result = array('success' => true, 'data' => $html);  header("Content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
//header("Content-Encoding: gzip");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: -1");
$json = json_encode($result);
print $json;

Comment: console.log($(".tags_filter").length) - можете пожалуйста сказать, что выведет в success

Comment: @JurijJazdanov 0 - вывел

Comment: @Dememos добавь всё в вопрос (нажав кнопку "Править"), чтоб было там наглядно видно.

Comment: отлично! мы нашли проблему. На момент вызова AJAX у вас еще нету эдемента .tags_filter.

Comment: @JurijJazdanov settimeout поможет, как думаете?

Comment: я бы обернул лучше вызов load_pictures в $( document ).ready(). SetTimeout помочь может, но это костыльное решение

Comment: @JurijJazdanov спасибо, буду пробовать.

Answer (score 0):

В коде проблемы с логикой.

Назначение `location.href` ведет к [асинхронной] перезагрузке страницы. Следом Вы сразу вызываете асинхронный ajax. Если ответ с новым содержимым страницы придет раньше, ответу нa ajax просто некуда будет возвращаться. Если ответ на ajax придет раньше, последующее содержимое новой старницы уничтожит весь эффект от обработки этого ответа.

Вызов `load_pictures` и сама эта функция должны находится в странице с адресом `data.redirect_url` и выполняться при ее загрузке.

Comment: Вопрос решен, спасибо.

Comment: @Dememos В обсуждении Вашего вопроса приняли участие четыре человека - четыре посторонних человека, потративших свое время, чтобы обдумать Вашу проблему и предложить решение. Сообщить этим людям, в чем состояло решение вопроса, - элементарная вежливость.